# A basic question about RF multiplexer practical use

Tags: multiplexer

Below shows an RF switch(multiplexer):

[image]

So what I understand is that the same RF input is routed to multiple outputs. This can be I guess used to couple the same RF signal to many different equipment such as spectrum analyser, oscilloscope ect.

But lets say the scenario is such that we have many signals from several devices which we can couple these as inputs to a device under test's input. I tried to draw it as follows:

[image]

Now as in my above example, we can select which analog input will be coupled to the ADC. I named it as MUX.

So in such a case are RF switches used as well? Or only analog multiplexers are used? If RF multiplexer can also be used, what could be the reason?
(is this called switch matrix?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can regard the [HMC252](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/hmc252.pdf) as a multiplexer if you want: -

[image]

> *So in such a case are RF switches used as well?*

No, you wouldn't use RF switches like the one above for regular low speed applications because regular low speed applications don't need inputs terminating in 50 ohms when disabled. Look at the picture above and note that when any of the 6 RF inputs are not used, those pins are internally connected to 50 ohms.

> *So what I understand is that the same RF input is routed to multiple
>   outputs.*

Or multiple RF inputs selectively coupled to a single output. They operate bidirectionally.

> *is this called switch matrix?*

It's not an unreasonable description if produced by a marketing guy but I wouldn't use the word matrix because it's misleading technically.

Comment: Great concise answer.